# How to find if a specific pixel of an image has a higher Red, Green, or Blue value in Python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, rgb

I am trying to find out if a certain pixel of an image has more of a Red Green or Blue value. I tried this code below:

```
im = Image.open("image.png")
x = 32
y = 32

pixel = im.load()

rgb = pixel[x,y]
rgb = int(rgb)

if rgb[0] > rgb[1,2]:
    print("Red")
elif rgb[1] > rgb[0,2]:
    print("Green")
elif rgb[2] > rgb[0,1]:
    print("Blue")
```

But its giving me this Error:

```
  File "d:\path\app.py", line 11, in <module>
    rgb = int(rgb)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong or if there's a better way of doing this!

Thanks
-Daniel

Comment: Perhaps you mean ```pixel((x,y))```

Comment: `int()` doesn't take a tuple argument.  if rgb is a tuple, leave it alone.  Then use ` if rgb[0] > rgb[1] and rgb[0]>rgb[2]` etc...

Comment: try rgb = [int(i) for i in rgb] for converting your rgb list to integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
red_image = Image.open("image.png")
red_image_rgb = red_image.convert("RGB")
rgb_pixel_value = red_image_rgb.getpixel((10,15))

if rgb_pixel_value[0]>rgb_pixel_value[1] and rgb_pixel_value[0]>rgb_pixel_value[2]:
    print("Red")
elif rgb_pixel_value[0]<rgb_pixel_value[2] and <rgb_pixel_value[1]<rgb_pixel_value[2]:
    print("Blue")
else:
    print("Green")
```

Here is an interactive program:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
root=tk.Tk()
def select_image():
    s=filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("PNG",'*.png'),("JPEG",'*.jpg')))
    if s!='':
        global red_image
        red_image = Image.open(s)
        image1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=s)
        lbl1.config(image=image1)
        lbl1.image=image1
        root.bind("<Motion>",check_pixel)
def check_pixel(event):
    red_image_rgb = red_image.convert("RGB")
    rgb_pixel_value = red_image_rgb.getpixel((event.x,event.y))
    lbl2.config(text=f"Red:   {rgb_pixel_value[0]}        Green:   {rgb_pixel_value[1]}        Blue:   {rgb_pixel_value[2]}")
    if rgb_pixel_value[0]>rgb_pixel_value[1] and rgb_pixel_value[0]>rgb_pixel_value[2]:
        lbl3.config(text="Red",fg="Red")
    elif rgb_pixel_value[0]<rgb_pixel_value[2]and rgb_pixel_value[1]<rgb_pixel_value[2]:
        lbl3.config(text="Blue",fg="Blue")
    else:
        lbl3.config(text="Green",fg="green")

button1=tk.Button(root,text='Select Image',command=select_image)
button1.pack()
lbl1=tk.Label(root)
lbl1.pack()
lbl2=tk.Label(root,text="Red:        Green:        Blue:")
lbl2.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
lbl3=tk.Label(root)
lbl3.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Notice that if we have R, G, B = 3, 1, 2, then R is the largest of the three, but R > G > B is False.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong here is that you are passing a `tuple` in the `int()` function which returns a `TypeError`.

A better way is to use Opencv for getting the values of R, G and B at your given (x, y)

```
import cv2

im = cv2.imread("image.png")

x, y = 32, 32


#get r, g and b values at (x, y)
r, g, b = im[x, y]
print(f"Pixel at ({x}, {y}) - Red: {r}, Green: {g}, Blue: {b}")

#then do your comparison
#following is an example
if (r>=g) and (r>=b):
    print("Red")
elif (g>=r) and (g>=b):
    print("Green")
else:
    print("Blue")
```